# What makes the cdf curve of a uniform distribution a constant positive slope?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, estimation

Assignment asks to explain why max of X will have the highest probability..

What is the reason why the probabilities of each random variable create a constant positive slope?

(max$_k$≤)=(1 ≤  ∩ 2 ≤  ∩ ⋯ n ≤ )  explain why

OR

=(1≤)(2≤)⋯ ( ≤) explain why

is this because of linearity and independence ?

This is the very first statistics class I've taken. I'm still learning.

*I am suppose to find an unbiased estimator for a given pmf for a uniform distribution.*

*pmf: $() = \frac{1}\theta{} \ \ \ \ (0 <  < )$*

Comment: The maximum of the observations is a good estimator of θ, It's the MLE. But it is obviously biased: The max must always be smaller than θ. A constant multiplier (depending on n) of the max can be used to get an unbiased estimator Let $X_{(n)}$ denote the max, Find its dist'n and then find $E[X_{(n)}].$. – BruceET 9 mins ago

Comment: @BruceET semi duplicate more trying to figure out why the independent probabilities are ascending order. Just need an answer to the assignment question "explain why" ...  I've proved / did the rest of showing the estimator to be unbiased. (n+1)/n *maxX was given.

Comment: The original observations are random. They are used to get the distribution of the max. Of course the sorted observations are not independent because  the $i$th order statistic $X_{(i)}$ is smaller than the $(i+1)$st order statistic $X_{(i+1)}.$